# Update model django through kwargs

Tags: python, django

How can i pass a dict which contain fields to update a Django model?
This is not to create an object, but to update it.

example:

```
obj = Object.objects.create(index=id, **fields)
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As long as the PK is the same, the existing row will be overwritten.

```
obj = Object(index=id, **fields)
obj.save()
```

Comment: You mean that it gonna create if in database is no field with index and update if there is field with that index? So we can call it update_or_create?

Comment: Ohh man!!! I already finished my method of create_or_update... Cose i found artikle that there is no method create or update in django.. There is artikle: http://blog.roseman.org.uk/2010/03/9/easy-create-or-update/    so its wrong article?

Comment: This is probably not what is wanted. It does not have update semantics: except for the fields specified in `fields`, `obj` will be overwritten with the defaults for a fresh instance of `Object`.

Comment: It only works if all fields are specified. If not, you're overwriting with default values...

Comment: The data fields not fill in the obj, obj hold data which query from database. Why this marked as answer then?

Answer (score 19):

```
def update_object(obj, **kwargs):
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        setattr(obj, k, v)
    obj.save()
```

Comment: This may not be what OP wanted because all the fields will be written to the db; not just those in `kwargs`, so possibly clobbering things. 1.5 does introduce an `update_fields` argument to `model.save`, although you would then have to repeat the field names.

Answer (score 13):

You can get a queryset of one object, and then update this:

```
model = Model.objects.filter(pk=pk)
model.update(**kwargs)
```

This will not call the .save() method on the object, though. I think it will only do one database query, however.

Note that if you didn't filter to one object (ie, the query got multiple objects: such as if you weren't querying on PK) it would update all of them.  If it filters to none, then nothing will be written to the database.

Having said that, I wasn't aware of Ignacio's solution. I quite like that.

Comment: If you manage to get multiple records while filtering on the PK then you have... bigger problems. Filtering to none isn't an issue though, since it's valid to issue an `UPDATE` query that doesn't match any records.

Comment: Yeah, I meant if you didn't query on PK, but on something else that was _supposed_ to be unique.

Answer (score 10):

If you know you want to create it:

```
Book.objects.create(**fields)
```

Assuming you need to check for an existing instance, you can find it with get or create:

```
instance, created = Book.objects.get_or_create(slug=slug, defaults=fields)
if not created:
    for attr, value in fields.iteritems(): 
        setattr(instance, attr, value)
    instance.save()
```

As mentioned in another answer, you can also use the `update` function on the queryset manager, but i believe that will not send any signals out (which may not matter to you if you aren't using them). However, you probably shouldn't use it to alter a single object:

```
Book.objects.filter(id=id).update(**fields)
```

Comment: +1 because it uses `defaults` and `setattr` to make sure that the contents of fields is applied to the object without losing any additional attributes that might already be set on an existing instance

Answer (score 8):

This question is a little old, but just to bring it up to date with recent Django developments - since 1.7 there has been an `update_or_create` method on querysets which works similarly to `get_or_create`.

In this case it could be used like:

```
obj, created = Object.objects.update_or_create(index=id, defaults={**fields})
```

Answer (score 2):

you can simply **update** using methods after `filter()` query

```
obj = Object.objects.filter(index=id).update(**fields) # fields your object(dict) may be **kwargs
```

if its a .get() method,

```
obj = Object.objects.get(index=id)
obj['key1'] = 'value1'
obj.save()
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just update the objects dict:

```py
obj.__dict__.update(fields)
obj.save()
```

Or for extra safety limit the save to only the fields you wish to update.

```py
obj.__dict__.update(fields)
obj.save(update_fields=fields.keys())
```