# How do I use a dictionary to update fields in Django models?

Tags: python, database, django

Suppose I have a model like this:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    num_pages = ...
    author = ...
    date = ...
```

Can I create a dictionary, and then insert or update the model using it?

```
d = {"num_pages":40, author:"Jack", date:"3324"}
```

Comment: Yes.  Try it.  Look up the `**` operator in the Python language reference manual.  http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#calls

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update model django through kwargs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108258/update-model-django-through-kwargs)

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Here's an example of create using your dictionary d:

```
Book.objects.create(**d)
```

To update an existing model, you will need to use the QuerySet `filter` method.  Assuming you know the `pk` of the Book you want to update:

```
Book.objects.filter(pk=pk).update(**d)
```

Comment: I think update only works on a QuerySet not on a single object.

Comment: Be careful: `update()` does not respect signals. See the answer by @leech below.

Comment: Hmm too bad update and update_or_create don't take using parameter, only save() does.

Answer (score 96):

Use `**` for creating a new model. Loop through the dictionary and use `setattr()` in order to update an existing model.

From Tom Christie's Django Rest Framework

https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py

```
for attr, value in validated_data.items():
    setattr(instance, attr, value)
instance.save()
```

Comment: Huh? Can you give an example? So, I would have to write a custom function that loops through the dictionary?

Comment: @TIMEX:  Please read.  http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#calls is very clear on how this works.

Comment: Could you explain why using `**` for updating might not be a good idea?

Comment: @Pocin using `queryset.update(**fields)` is a good idea according to django docs. Quote: "If you’re just updating a record and don’t need to do anything with the model object, the most efficient approach is to call update(), rather than loading the model object into memory."

Comment: Good answer, the call is very explicit. Not a fan of filter(...).update(...) since bungling the filter can lead to mass overwrites.

Comment: I agree with Bryant Jackson.  And also it seems a bit easier to understand the code when operating on a single instance.

Answer (score 77):

If you know you would like to create it:

```
Book.objects.create(**d)
```

Assuming you need to check for an existing instance, you can find it with get or create:

```
instance, created = Book.objects.get_or_create(slug=slug, defaults=d)
if not created:
    for attr, value in d.items(): 
        setattr(instance, attr, value)
    instance.save()
```

As mentioned in another answer, you can also use the `update` function on the queryset manager, but i believe that will not send any signals out (which may not matter to you if you aren't using them). However, you probably shouldn't use it to alter a single object:

```
Book.objects.filter(id=id).update()
```

Comment: Doesn't your create code leads to 2 database hits? One for creating, the other for `.save()`?

Comment: Yes, but not to save. If it has been created, there will be one to lookup the Book (SELECT), then another to update it (an UPDATE not INSERT statement will be generated). If the book doesn't exist, there is one to look it up (SELECT) and create it (INSERT).

Comment: `that will not send any signals out`: cannot stress this out enough.

Answer (score 12):

if you have already Django object and you want to update it's field, you may do it without filter. because you have it already, in this case, yoy may :

```
your_obj.__dict__.update(your_dict)
your_obj.save()
```

Comment: Please add a ".": your_obj.__dict__.update(your_dict)

Comment: TLDR : Won't work for object fields. Details: If your fields are not basic types like str, int ie an object like Entry. It won't work.

Answer (score 2):

To update one record you can use very handy function:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    num_pages = ...
    author = ...
    date = ...

    def update(self,*args, **kwargs):
            for name,values in kwargs.items():
                try:
                    setattr(self,name,values)
                except KeyError:
                    pass
            self.save()
```

and then:

```
d = {"num_pages":40, author:"Jack", date:"3324"}
book = Book.objects.first()
book.update(**d)
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding on top of other answers, here's a bit more secure version to prevent messing up with related fields:

```
def is_simple_editable_field(field):
    return (
            field.editable
            and not field.primary_key
            and not isinstance(field, (ForeignObjectRel, RelatedField))
    )

def update_from_dict(instance, attrs, commit):
    allowed_field_names = {
        f.name for f in instance._meta.get_fields()
        if is_simple_editable_field(f)
    }

    for attr, val in attrs.items():
        if attr in allowed_field_names:
            setattr(instance, attr, val)

    if commit:
        instance.save()
```

It checks, that field you're trying to update is editable, is not primary key and is not one of related fields.

Example usage:

```
book = Book.objects.first()
update_from_dict(book, {"num_pages":40, author:"Jack", date:"3324"})
```

The luxury DRF serializers `.create` and `.update` methods have is that there is limited and validated set of fields, which is not the case for manual update.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Thierry Lams answer:

While the `Book.objects.filter(pk=pk).update(**d)` works nicely, it also has the side effect of saving the object, which may not be desirable.

If a save is not what you want, try this:

```
d = {"num_pages":40, author:"Jack", date:"3324"}
book =  Book.objects.get(pk=pk)
book.__dict__ = {**book.__dict__, **d}
```