# How to save array data in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

How to save array data in django?

I have an array and need to save it.

```
        fields= {
            "description":"Medida",
            "name": "medida",
            "tipo": "tipo"
        }


Produto.objects.create(fields)
```

It does not work.

Comment: Posible duplicated question. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503925/how-do-i-use-a-dictionary-to-update-fields-in-django-models

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use a dictionary to update fields in Django models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503925/how-do-i-use-a-dictionary-to-update-fields-in-django-models)

Answer (score 0):

You have to unpack the array.

`**fields` will unpack the key and value pair into keyword and arguments in the function call:

`Produto.objects.create(**fields)`